# Update all records status to 1 and check if all records have been update status to 1

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a SQL table tbl_messages, I am using this to send messages and set status 1 as not submitted and 2 as submitted or message send, I am able to set the status of all send messages to 2, but want to check if all records are set to 2 and once all the records are set to 2 (which means message send) i want to archive the table, is there any query to check if all records are set to status 2? or do i have to count the records first and then check the status ?

Comment: Other than by querying ? no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following query.

```sql
select count(*) from tbl_messages where status != 2;
```

if this returns count > 0 means still non sent(status = 1) messages are present in table.

if count == 0 means all messages are present with status = 2 then archive it.